# How to find and group together records with leading zeros and their counter part (duplicate) record that has had the leading zeros removed in a DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a DB that has correctly formatted records with leading zeros. However, the same records, except with the leading zeros stripped (thanks excel) got added to the DB also. In essence creating duplicate records that are following the wrong numbering convention. So, the DB has records with correct ID's such as...

```
01234,
01122,
01323,
```

but also with incorrect ID numbers like

```
1234,
1122,
1323,
```

I am trying to do a query that will return a result set grouping these duplicate records in the DB like this:

```
01234,
1234,
01122,
1122,
01323,
1323,
```

Any thoughts are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I used `CROSS APPLY` to re-query the table.

The query in the `CROSS APPLY` looks for "matches" where the they values would be equal if they were both `CAST` as integers, but are not equal as string values. Then, to clean up the result set a little, I limited it to where the base value doesn't start with a zero character. Otherwise, the query was pulling the matches in both directions, which didn't seem useful.

Data set up:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
  (
    idCol VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
  );

INSERT @t
  (
    idCol
  )
VALUES
  ('01234')
 ,('01122')
 ,('01321')
 ,('1234')
 ,('1122')
 ,('1321')
 ,('00012');
```

The query:

```
SELECT
  t.idCol
 ,c.idCol
FROM
  @t AS t
CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT
      idCol
    FROM
      @t
    WHERE
      idCol = CAST(t.idCol AS INT)
      AND idCol <> t.idCol
      AND LEFT(idCol, 1) <> '0'
  ) AS c;
```

Results:

```
+-------+-------+
| idCol | idCol |
+-------+-------+
| 01234 |  1234 |
| 01122 |  1122 |
| 01321 |  1321 |
+-------+-------+
```